# Get OPCItem from ClientHandles in DataChange Event - OPCAutomation.dll

Tags: vb.net, plc, opc

Is it possible to get the OPCItem from a Group using the ClientHandle value?

Pseudo example:

```
Dim Server As OPCServer
Dim Groups As OPCGroups
Dim WithEvents Group1 as OPCGroup
Dim ItemGroup as OPCItems
Dim Item as OPCItem

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Server.Connect("MyServer")
    Group1 = New OPCGroup()
    Group1.Name = "Group1"
    Group1.IsSubscribed = True
    Group1.OPCItems.Add("Item1", 1)
    Server.OPCGroups.Add(Group1)
End Sub

Private Sub Group1_DataChange(TransactionID As Integer, NumItems As Integer, ByRef ClientHandles As Array, ByRef ItemValues As Array, ByRef Qualities As Array, ByRef TimeStamps As Array) Handles Group1.DataChange

Dim Browser as OPCBrowser = Server.CreateBrowser()
Browser.ShowBranches()
Browser.DataType = vbInteger
Browser.ShowLeafs()

Dim qualityValue as Integer
For q As Integer = 1 To Qualities.Length
    qualityValue = Qualities.GetValue(n)
    If qualityValue = 192 Then
        'HERE is where I want to get the OPCItem by using the ClientHandles
        'I can use the ClientHandle to get the Value, but I'd also like to get the ItemID to do validation against.

        Dim itemClientHandle as Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ClientHandles.GetValue(n))
        Dim itemValueByClientHandle as String = ItemValues.GetValue(n).ToString()

    End If
Next

'It is possible to use the OPCBrowser to get the Item Names but how do I correlate the two?
    Dim itemNames as New List(Of String)
    For n As Integer = 1 To OPCBrowser.Count
        itemNames.Add(OPCBrowser.Item(i))
    Next
' Do More Stuff
End Sub
```

There is a request to enhance an existing client application to be paused when a value is sent from the client to the OPC Server and wait for the bit tag to switch as in indication the process has finished. This part is built; however, there are multiple items (tags) in the group and there needs to be a way of identifying the correct items bit value was changed.